# Как добавить полосу прокрутки?

Tags: php, html, css

Здравствуйте, каким образом можно добавить полосу прокрутки на сайт (я имею виду не стандартную полосу в нижней или правой части экрана, а где то в середине чтобы прокручивать определённую часть страницы по горизонтали)?

Comment: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/  и проще найти плагин на js

Comment: Так тебе надо сделать просто прокрутку не для все страницы а для конкретного div элемента

Answer (score -1):

Для любого элемента типа `<div id="div1">текст</div>`, можно задать стиль отображения.
CSS пример:

```
#div1 {
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  overflow:auto;
  overflow-y:hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```